# How to add smileys in java swing?

Tags: java, swing

I am developing a chat application in java swing in which I would like to add smileys, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific than that ... unless you are happy with solutions like `System.out.print(":-)");`.

Comment: okie, collective smileys as in gtalk or yahoo messengers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> #### Autoreplace smiles text with appropriate images in JEditorPane
>
> To support the autoreplacing we need a `JEditorPane` with `StyledEditorKit` (or extension class) to provide images in text. We just add a `DocumentListener` to process text insert events. After inserting we check whether the changed text contains smiles string - the ":)". If it contains we replace the smile text with an appropriate image.
>
> The example provides only one smile support - the ":)" string but can be easy extended.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.*;
 
public class AutoreplaceSmiles extends JEditorPane {
    static ImageIcon SMILE_IMG=createImage();
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Autoreplace :) with Smiles images example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final AutoreplaceSmiles app = new AutoreplaceSmiles();
        app.setEditorKit(new StyledEditorKit());
        app.initListener();
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(app);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);
 
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
 
    public AutoreplaceSmiles() {
        super();
    }
 
    private void initListener() {
        getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
                final DocumentEvent e=event;
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (e.getDocument() instanceof StyledDocument) {
                            try {
                                StyledDocument doc=(StyledDocument)e.getDocument();
                                int start= Utilities.getRowStart(AutoreplaceSmiles.this,Math.max(0,e.getOffset()-1));
                                int end=Utilities.getWordStart(AutoreplaceSmiles.this,e.getOffset()+e.getLength());
                                String text=doc.getText(start, end-start);
 
                                int i=text.indexOf(":)");
                                while(i>=0) {
                                    final SimpleAttributeSet attrs=new SimpleAttributeSet(
                                       doc.getCharacterElement(start+i).getAttributes());
                                    if (StyleConstants.getIcon(attrs)==null) {
                                        StyleConstants.setIcon(attrs, SMILE_IMG);
                                        doc.remove(start+i, 2);
                                        doc.insertString(start+i,":)", attrs);
                                    }
                                    i=text.indexOf(":)", i+2);
                                }
                            } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            }
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            }
        });
    }
 
    static ImageIcon createImage() {
        BufferedImage res=new BufferedImage(17, 17, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g=res.getGraphics();
        ((Graphics2D)g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillOval(0,0,16,16);
 
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawOval(0,0,16,16);
 
        g.drawLine(4,5, 6,5);
        g.drawLine(4,6, 6,6);
 
        g.drawLine(11,5, 9,5);
        g.drawLine(11,6, 9,6);
 
        g.drawLine(4,10, 8,12);
        g.drawLine(8,12, 12,10);
        g.dispose();
 
        return new ImageIcon(res);
    }
}
```

Source: http://java-sl.com/tip_autoreplace_smiles.html

Comment: Sorry StanislavL, I didn't remember where I copied that code from. I added the website reference to my copy of the source.

Comment: Thank you. I think your code is slightly different. Another image and another trigger are set. Would be better to create the image once and pass the reference rather than recreating it though. But definitely both way it works:)

Comment: @StanislavL: Sorry to intrude, [_java-sl_](http://java-sl.com/) appears unresponsive; last [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20211215000000*/http://java-sl.com).

Answer (score 7):

Here is some simple code that I found a long time ago on the web. I don't really like that is uses a caret listener. You should probably use a DocumentListener or a DocumentFilter. But it will give you an idea of how you can use a custom Icon to represent a smiley.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class Smiley
    extends JFrame {
    //autoreplacing :) with picture
    JTextPane p = new JTextPane();
    public Smiley() throws Exception {
        p.setEditorKit(new StyledEditorKit());
        getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        SimpleAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setIcon(attrs, getImage());
        p.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
            public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) p.getDocument();
                            String text = doc.getText(0, p.getDocument().getLength());
                            int index = text.indexOf(":)");
                            int start = 0;
                            while (index > -1) {
                                Element el = doc.getCharacterElement(index);
                                if (StyleConstants.getIcon(el.getAttributes()) == null) {
                                    doc.remove(index, 2);
                                    SimpleAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
                                    StyleConstants.setIcon(attrs, getImage());
                                    doc.insertString(index, ":)", attrs);
                                }
                                start = index + 2;
                                index = text.indexOf(":)", start);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(400, 400);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Smiley test11 = new Smiley();
        test11.show();
    }

    protected ImageIcon getImage() {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(15, 15, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawOval(0, 0, 14, 14);
        g.drawLine(4, 9, 9, 9);
        g.drawOval(4, 4, 1, 1);
        g.drawOval(10, 4, 1, 1);
        return new ImageIcon(bi);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should accept StanislavL's answer as he is the original author of the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can copy these Unicode characters and use them: ☺ ☻

In Java strings, these will be `"\u263a"` and `"\u263b"`.

Comment: Is there no separate jar's for that?

Comment: @harishtps: No JAR; just a font with the required glyph. Here's an [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons).

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.bulletapp.dragontest;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Smiley extends JApplet
{
    public static final int FACE_DIAMETER = 200;
    public static final int X_FACE = 100;
    public static final int Y_FACE = 50;

    public static final int EYE_WIDTH = 10;
    public static final int EYE_HEIGHT = 20;
    public static final int X_RIGHT_EYE = 155;
    public static final int Y_RIGHT_EYE = 95;
    public static final int X_LEFT_EYE = 230;
    public static final int Y_LEFT_EYE = Y_RIGHT_EYE;

    public static final int Y_NOSE = 135;

    public static final int MOUTH_WIDTH = 100;
    public static final int MOUTH_HEIGHT = 50;
    public static final int X_MOUTH = 150;
    public static final int Y_MOUTH = 175;
    public static final int MOUTH_DEGREES_SHOWN = 180;

    public int noseDiameter = 10;         // initial value of the nose's diameter
    public int xNose = 195;               // initial value of the nose's x-position
    public int mouthStartAngle = 180;     // initial start angle of the mouth's arc
    public Color eyeColor = Color.BLACK;  // initial eye color

    public void paint(Graphics graphics)
    {
        // Draw face circle:
        graphics.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        graphics.fillOval(X_FACE, Y_FACE, FACE_DIAMETER, FACE_DIAMETER);
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.drawOval(X_FACE, Y_FACE, FACE_DIAMETER, FACE_DIAMETER);

        // Draw eyes:
        graphics.setColor(eyeColor);
        graphics.fillOval(X_RIGHT_EYE, Y_RIGHT_EYE, EYE_WIDTH, EYE_HEIGHT);
        graphics.fillOval(X_LEFT_EYE, Y_LEFT_EYE, EYE_WIDTH, EYE_HEIGHT);

        // Draw nose:
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.fillOval(xNose, Y_NOSE, noseDiameter, noseDiameter);

        // Draw mouth:
        graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
        graphics.drawArc(X_MOUTH, Y_MOUTH, MOUTH_WIDTH, MOUTH_HEIGHT,
            mouthStartAngle, MOUTH_DEGREES_SHOWN);
    }

    public void modifyFace()
    {
        String inputString;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Which would you like to change?\nMOUTH, NOSE, or EYES");
        inputString = keyboard.nextLine();

        // your code goes here, you do not have to modify any code before this point

        // you do not have to modify code after this point
    }

    public static void addAppletToFrame(JApplet applet)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Smiley!");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(applet);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        applet.init();
        applet.start();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Smiley smiley = new Smiley();
        smiley.modifyFace();

        addAppletToFrame(smiley);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.awt.*;
public class SmileyFace {

   public static void main(String[] args){


        Frame f = new Frame("Smile Face");
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setVisible(true);

        Graphics g;
        g = f.getGraphics();


        while (true)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawOval(100, 100, 100, 100);
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillOval(120, 130, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(160, 130, 20, 20);
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawLine(130, 170, 135, 175);
            g.drawLine(135, 175, 163, 175);
            g.drawLine(163, 175, 168, 170);
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.drawString("Hello", 210, 190);



        }


    }
}
```